# Extracting Info From a .txt File and Converting to int

Tags: python, regex, list, input, findall

I'm essentially trying to write a code that divides my tips each night into seperate savings plans and writes that to a .txt file.

I'm having issues reading the old total from the text file and adding the supplimentary tips then rewriting the product to the .txt file.

Please tell me if this is a ridiculous way of doing things and I need to change my whole way of doing things.

```
import re


savings1 = 0  
savings2 = 0
savings3 = 0
savings4 = 0
savings5 = 0
savings6 = 0
```

'initint' takes in the value.

```
initint = input('Please input todays tips, or Enter to exit:')
```

Then the while loop divides the value into respective percentages and allocates them to my savings counters.

```
while initint != "":
    
    savings1 += (int(initint)*0.50)
    savings2 += (int(initint)*0.05)
    savings3 += (int(initint)*0.25)
    savings4 += (int(initint)*0.10)
    savings5 += (int(initint)*0.05)
    savings6 += (int(initint)*0.05)
    
    initint = input('Please input todays tips, or Enter to exit:')
    
    if initint == "":
        break
```

This is where (I think) the trouble comes in.

The idea is to use regex to identify numbers in the txt file then return them so I can add them to the value that the while loop divided up.

At the moment I can only print them.

```
with open('divisions.txt','r+') as r:
    for line in r:
        
        I = re.findall('\d+\d', line)
        
        print(I)
```

So the output is looking like this at the moment (if the old input was 500).

```
[]
[]
['250']
['25']
['125']
['50']
['25']
['25']
```

The first issue is that it's returning lists.

The second issue is that it's returning 2 empty lists from the first 2 lines with no digits which is a bit strange.

I have no idea what I would even google to start this step.

---

The last step writes the totals to the text file.

```
with open('divisions.txt','w') as f:
    
    f.write(f'Savings Plan:\n\nsavings1: {savings1}\nsavings2: {savings2}\nsavings3: {savings3}\nsavings4: {savings4}\nsavings5: {savings5}\nsavings6: {savings6}\n')
```

Let me know if I'm being silly but would very much appreciate it if anyone is willing to help.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just as a note, `\d+\d` matches as least 2 digits

Comment: Rather than writing the values out as plain text which you then have to parse, you could output the data as JSON (or any other machine parsable structured language) which will be easy to import and use.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex assumes that all numbers are double digits or more, I would change this to `r'\d+'`.

The `findall` function always returns a list, but you can check if the length is more than 0 and grab the first number.

```
with open('divisions.txt','r+') as r:
    for line in r:
    
        I = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
        if (len(I) > 0):
            number = I[0]
            print(number)
```

Comment: thank you! One more question, do you know how i could name each result as they're extracted in the for loop? like each integer produced could be named int1, int2 so on so fourth

Comment: Sure! You could change the `for line in r` to `for idx, line in enumerate(r)` where the idx would be the line number. If you want the number to be independant from the line numbers which it is found at, you could make a seperate counter and increment it when the if check is true.